Almost sure limit of $W_t + at$ for $a\neq 0$
It is easy to show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{W_t}{t}=0$ almost surely.
My lecture notes state simply that this "implies" that Brownian Motion with drift $W_t +at$ is infinity for a>0 and minus infinity for a<0. Once you factor $t(\frac{W_t}{t}+a)$ I do not know how to proceed. Product rule cannot be invoked and I am not sure how to handle the limit being taken almost surely. So far I have attempted to consider each realisation of $W_t$ for each $\omega$ s.t. $\frac{W_t(\omega)}{t}$ converges to 0, but this leaves me with no control over how quickly this converges to 0 and so I cannot compare it to $t$. Any help is appreciated.

Product rule can be used because $W_t/t+a\to a>0$ (or $<0$), so $W_t+at\to \infty \cdot a=\infty$ (if $a>0$)

I don't understand any of the problems you've commented on.  Why can you not use the "product rule for limits"?  (If it's because one limit goes to $\infty$ so doesn't exist, this is an easy fix)  Why do you care about how quickly an almost-sure realization of $W_t/t$ goes to zero?  (Do you want to show the limit is uniform?  If so, it's not, but that shouldn't matter)

This has nothing to do with Probability Theory. Just replace $W_t$ by  a non-random function and use a simple Calculus argument to prove the result.
